# Get CSS properties to use in Rails variables and DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the css attribute when I click on multiple divs named scale-up.

However, I want to store the imported css properties in Rails variables and DB.

The final thing I want is to get the Css properties when I click on them and have them populate the form automatically. This data is stored in a column called color.

**The code I tried was:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".scale-up-center").click(function() {
            var color = $(".scale-up-center").css("background-color");
            $(".first_scale").css("background-color", color);
        })
    })
```

I've heard that you can use ajax, but when you look at the guide it's different from what I want.

**Main view image**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScEGt.png)

Comment: Is this really what you want to achieve? To save some colors in the db? What is happening on the page? What is the purpose of the form?

Comment: I have added a color column to the posts controller.
And when the user submits a text, there are colored divs around the text_area.
And when I click on the div, I get the background-color property of the div.
This is what I can do now.
And I want to utilize the color column where the css property is stored when I finally submit.

Comment: Okay. You want the user to select a color for a post. Is that the purpose of the form?

Comment: Yes. When the user selects the color of the div for the post, I want to save it to the form and save it when I submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is a bit brittle. When your css colors are changed, you still have old, invalid colors in your database. Users can also manipulate the form value to inject unwanted colors. You do not have a clean separation of your representation and your logic.

Instead, define some constants in your model for all available colors. Also validate that the passed in value is one of the valid colors:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  COLORS = ["none", "red", "green", "blue"]
  validates :color, inclusion: { in: COLORS }
end
```

In your view, let the user select the color via a radio-button:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= label :color %>
  <% Post::COLORS.each do |c| %>
    <div class="color-<%= c %>">
      <%= f.radio_button :color, c %> 
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Now you can define the representation in your css:

```
form .color-red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

// ...
```

You can still add some javascript to color your whole text field.

Comment: Thank you first for your answers.

What I want is to get the css property (background-color) of the area when I click on a div area consisting of several circles like a picture rather than a radio button, and enter the css property in the color form and save it in the color column .

I added a main view image of my project to the post.

Comment: You can style your form as you like. You can display the radio buttons like these circles.

Comment: Can I change the appearance of the radio button? I will try once. Thank!!